# How can I use XML attributes when converting into a hash with from_xml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, hash

I have an XML element with multiple child elements that use the same ID.  The child elements are distinguishable by a "`size`" attribute.  When I create a hash using `from_xml` it lumps all these child elements 1 field.

How do I parse these child elements into different fields based on the XML attribute?

XML:

```
<artist rank="48">
 <name>KISS</name>
  <image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/3329738.jpg</image>
  <image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/3329738.jpg</image>
  <image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/3329738.jpg</image>
  <image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/3329738.jpg</image>
  <image size="mega">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/3329738/KISS+04.jpg</image>
</artist>
```

Ruby:

```
>>xml = "<artist rank='48'><name>KISS</name><image size='small'>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/3329738.jpg</image><image size='medium'>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/3329738.jpg</image><image size='large'>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/3329738.jpg</image><image size='extralarge'>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/3329738.jpg</image><image size='mega'>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/3329738/KISS+04.jpg</image></artist>"
=> "<artist rank='48'><name>KISS</name><image size='small'>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/3329738.jpg</image><image size='medium'>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/3329738.jpg</image><image size='large'>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/3329738.jpg</image><image size='extralarge'>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/3329738.jpg</image><image size='mega'>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/3329738/KISS+04.jpg</image></artist>"
>>h = Hash.from_xml xml
=> {"artist"=>{"name"=>"KISS", "rank"=>"48", "image"=>["http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/3329738.jpg", "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/3329738.jpg", "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/3329738.jpg", "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/3329738.jpg", "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/3329738/KISS+04.jpg"]}}
```

What I want:

```
=> {"artist"=>{"name"=>"KISS", "rank"=>"48", "image_small"=>"http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/3329738.jpg", "image_medium"="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/3329738.jpg", "image_large"="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/3329738.jpg", "image_extralarge"="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/3329738.jpg", image_mega"="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/3329738/KISS+04.jpg"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hash.to_xml` currently won't do that. It's really just meant for the simplest cases.

But, there's an [open ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1598-preserve-xml-attributes-with-hashfrom_xml-and-activeresource) with some proposed patches. Still, I would recommend something like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse your XML.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.  FWIW, from_xml added the image elements as an array.  So I was able to access the content for each image element using the array location, example: h['artist']['image'][1]