# Keeping attributes when converting XML to Ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, xml-parsing

I have a large XML document I am looking to parse. In this document, many tags have different attributes within them. For example:

```
<album>
 <song-name type="published">Do Re Mi</song-name>
</album>
```

Currently, I am using Rail's hash-parsing library by requiring `'active_support/core_ext/hash'`.

When I convert it to a hash, it drops the attributes. It returns:

```
{"album"=>{"song-name"=>"Do Re Mi"}}
```

How do I maintain those attributes, in this case, the `type="published"` attribute?

This seems to have been previously been asked in "[How can I use XML attributes when converting into a hash with from_xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099027/how-can-i-use-xml-attributes-when-converting-into-a-hash-with-from-xml)", which had no conclusive answer, but that was from 2010, and I'm curious if things have changed since then. Or, I wonder if you know of an alternative way of parsing this XML so that I could still have the attribute information included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting XML to a hash isn't a good solution. You're left with a hash that is more difficult to parse than the original XML. Plus, if the XML is too big, you'll be left with a hash that won't fit into memory, and can't be processed, whereas the original XML could be parsed using a SAX parser.

Assuming the file isn't going to overwhelm your memory when loaded, I'd recommend using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) to parse it, doing something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

class Album

  attr_reader :song_name, :song_type
  def initialize(song_name, song_type)
    @song_name = song_name
    @song_type = song_type
  end
end

xml = <<EOT
<xml>
  <album>
   <song-name type="published">Do Re Mi</song-name>
  </album>
  <album>
    <song-name type="unpublished">Blah blah blah</song-name>
  </album>
</xml>
EOT

albums = []
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.search('album').each do |album|
  song_name = album.at('song-name')
  albums << Album.new(
      song_name.text,
      song_name['type']
    )
end

puts albums.first.song_name
puts albums.last.song_type
```

Which outputs:

```
Do Re Mi
unpublished
```

The code starts by defining a suitable object to be used to hold the data you want. When the XML is parsed into a DOM, the code will loop through all the `<album>` nodes, and extract the information, defining an instance of the class, and appending it to the `albums` array.

After running you'd have an array you would walk, and process each item, storing it into a database, or manipulating it however you want. Though, if your goal is to insert that information into a database, you'd be smarter to let the DBM read the XML and import it directly.

Comment: Friggin brilliant, Tin Man. I'm glad you stopped me early on. This is incredibly helpful.

Comment: I make no claims it's brilliant, it's just how I'd do it. Let us know if you run into any other issues. Parsing XML/HTML can be quite frustrating on occasion.

Answer (score 4):

It's problem with active support XMLConverter class
Please add following code to any of your initializers file.

```
module ActiveSupport
    class XMLConverter
        private
            def become_content?(value)
                value['type'] == 'file' || (value['__content__'] && (value.keys.size == 1 && value['__content__'].present?))
            end
    end
end
```

It will gives you output like following.

Ex Input XML

```
xml = '<album>
   <song-name type="published">Do Re Mi</song-name>
</album>'

Hash.from_xml(xml)
```

Output will be

```
{"album"=>{"song_name"=>{"type"=>"published", "__content__"=>"Do Re Mi"}}}
```

Comment: Yeah but this is not ideal as well, because if from such hash we try to construct the xml back again 

`{"album"=>{"song_name"=>{"type"=>"published", "__content__"=>"Do Re Mi"}}}.to_xml`

We get

`<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<hash>\n  <album>\n    <song-name>\n      <type>published</type>\n      <__content__>Do Re Mi</__content__>\n    </song-name>\n  </album>`

Which is not the original.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think its the garbage method, it's checking the type attribute and if it doesn't return a hash it'll return true which in the method become_hash? returns false. Which is the last check in the process_hash method. So it'll return nil for type attribute and won't build the hash for it.

For those interested what I'm talking about is in the active support gem active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions.rb

`module ActiveSupport
  class XMLConverter
    private
    def garbage?(value)
      false
    end
  end
end`

I just defaulted it to false and it worked for me but it might not be for everyone.

Answer (score -2):

As in the question you linked above, [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) is the (short) answer.

If you can provide some sample code, someone might come up with better answers.